# ¿Por qué no me quiere enlazar estos archivos?

Tags: c++, socket

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer sockets y todo va muy bien hasta que cuando corro el `main` de prueba me empieza a fallar porque no logra encontrar los métodos que son del socket.

He estado buscando en muchas páginas pero no he encontrado el problema. Este es el código:

Socket.cpp:

```
#include "Socket.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int sockfd;
Socket::Socket(char t,bool)
{

int tipo;
if(t == 's'){
tipo = SOCK_STREAM;
}
else if(t == 'd'){
tipo = SOCK_DGRAM;
}
sockfd = socket(AF_INET,tipo,0);
if(sockfd == -1){
perror("Error con sockfd");
}
}

Socket::~Socket(){
close(sockfd);
}

int Connect(char const * Host, int Port){
struct sockaddr_in host_addr;
host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_aton( Host,  &host_addr.sin_addr );
host_addr.sin_port = htons( Port );
int c;
int len = sizeof( host_addr );
c = connect(sockfd, (sockaddr *) & host_addr, len );
if(c == -1){
perror("Error en connect");
return -1;
}
return c;
}

int Read(char * text, int len){
int r;
r = read(sockfd,text,len);
if(r == -1){
perror("Error en read");
return -1;  
}
return r;

}


int Write(char const * text, int len){
int w;
w = write(sockfd,text,len);
if(w == -1){
perror("Error en write");
return -1;
}
return w;
}

int Shutdown(int tipo){
int i;
i = shutdown(sockfd,tipo);
if(i == -1){
perror("Error en shutdown");
return -1;
}
return i;
}
```

Socket.h:

```
#ifndef SOCKET_H
#define SOCKET_H

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

class Socket
{
public:
    Socket(char = 's', bool ipv6 = false);
    ~Socket();
     int Connect(char const* Host, int Port);
     int Read(char * text, int len);
     int Write(char const * text, int len);
     int Shutdown(int);



protected:

private:
struct sockaddr
{
unsigned short sa_family;  /* familia de la dirección */
char sa_data[14];          /* 14 bytes de la dirección del protocolo */
};

struct sockaddr_in
{
short int sin_family;        /* Familia de la Dirección              */
unsigned short int sin_port; /* Puerto                               */
struct in_addr sin_addr;     /* Dirección de Internet                */
unsigned char sin_zero[8];   /* Del mismo tamaño que struct sockaddr */
};

struct in_addr
{
unsigned   long s_addr;
};
};

#endif // SOCKET_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Socket.h"

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {

Socket s;
char a[512];

s.Connect( "163.178.104.187", 80 );
s.Write(  "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: redes.ecci\r\n\r\n", 36 );
s.Read( a, 512 );
printf( "%s\n", a);
}
```

El mensaje de error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
main.o: En la función `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x41): referencia a `Socket::Connect(char const*, int)'        sin definir
main.cpp:(.text+0x57): referencia a `Socket::Write(char const*, int)' sin     definir
main.cpp:(.text+0x72): referencia a `Socket::Read(char*, int)' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [makefile:4: ProyectoSockets] Error 1
```

y como pueden ver está todo enlazado, los nombres están bien escritos y lo estoy compilando con g++. Muchas gracias

Makefile:

```
all: ProyectoSockets

ProyectoSockets: Socket.o main.o
    g++ -o ProyectoSockets Socket.o main.o

main.o: main.cpp Socket.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

Socket.o: Socket.cpp Socket.h
    g++ -c Socket.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf*.o
```

Comment: Daniel, incluye el archivo Makefile en la pregunta, en principio pareciera que el linker no está encontrando o no se le esta indicando el objeto Socket. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ya lo agregué

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problema

Revisando tu codigo es facil determinar que en el archivo `Socket.cpp`, has inicializado unas funciones:

```
int Connect(char const * Host, int Port){
...
}

int Read(char * text, int len){
...
}

int Write(char const * text, int len){
...
}

int Shutdown(int tipo){
...
}
```

Evidentemente estas son funciones que deberian pertenecer a la clase Socket, pero tu no las estas asociando con la clase, basta entonces editar las declaraciones dejandolas a todas antecedidas por el nombre de la clase `Socket::`, asi:

```
int Socket::Connect(char const * Host, int Port){
...
}

int Socket::Read(char * text, int len){
...
}

int Socket::Write(char const * text, int len){
...
}

int Socket::Shutdown(int tipo){
...
}
```

Al ejecutar make, todo se va a enlazar correctamente, msa te va a arrojar este error:

```
Socket.cpp: In member function ‘int Socket::Connect(const char*, int)’:
Socket.cpp:32:51: error: cannot convert ‘Socket::sockaddr*’ to ‘const sockaddr*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int connect(int, const sockaddr*, socklen_t)’
 c = connect(sockfd, (sockaddr *) & host_addr, len );
                                                   ^
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'Socket.o' failed
make: *** [Socket.o] Error 1
```

Que ya se debe a algun problema dejado en el codigo fuente.